# Center ul sprite navigation

Tags: css, html-lists, sprite, center

I created a sprite image menu within WordPress using the following CSS:

```
/* 04 Microsites Navigation */
.micrositescontainer {
    background: url('img/microsites_main_bkg.jpg');
}

.micrositestopnav ul {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 20%;
}

.micrositestopnav .horizontal-menu ul li {
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
}

/* Microsites Menu Items Start Here]*/
.micrositestopnav .menu-item-8449 a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}

.micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8449.menu-item-object-page:hover > a, .micrositestopnav ul ul:hover > a, .micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8449.menu-item-object-page a:focus {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: 0 -125px;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}

.micrositestopnav li.current-menu-item.menu-item-8449 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current-menu-ancestor.menu-item-8449 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_item.menu-item-8449 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_ancestor.menu-item-8449 > a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: 0 -125px;
}

.micrositestopnav .menu-item-8453 a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -200px 0px;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}

.micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8453.menu-item-object-page:hover > a, .micrositestopnav ul ul:hover > a, .micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8453.menu-item-object-page a:focus {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -200px -125px;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}

.micrositestopnav li.current-menu-item.menu-item-8453 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current-menu-ancestor.menu-item-8453 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_item.menu-item-8453 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_ancestor.menu-item-8453 > a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -200px -125px;
}

.micrositestopnav .menu-item-8456 a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -400px 0;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}

.micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8456.menu-item-object-page:hover > a, .micrositestopnav ul ul:hover > a, .micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8456.menu-item-object-page a:focus {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -400px -125px;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}

.micrositestopnav li.current-menu-item.menu-item-8456 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current-menu-ancestor.menu-item-8450 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_item.menu-item-8456 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_ancestor.menu-item-8456 > a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -400px -125px;
}

.micrositestopnav .menu-item-8481 a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -600px 0;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}

.micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8481.menu-item-object-page:hover > a, .micrositestopnav ul ul:hover > a, .micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8481.menu-item-object-page a:focus {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -600px -125px;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}

.micrositestopnav li.current-menu-item.menu-item-8481 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current-menu-ancestor.menu-item-8481 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_item.menu-item-8481 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_ancestor.menu-item-8481 > a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -600px -125px;
}
/* Microsites Menu Items End Here]*/
/* 04 Microsites Navigation End */
```

The menu works perfect but the other day when inspecting the site on `Chrome Linux` `33.0.1750.152` I noticed that the horizontal layout of the sprite images are not lined up in the same area. I believe that using the following code (padding-left: 20%) is causing this problem:

```
.micrositestopnav ul {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 20% ;
}
```

I think my desire of wanting to center the sprite menu was poorly achieved by applying this quick solution above.  I would like to know how a more experienced coder would center this area.

You can see the menu working on here http://betabooks.matthewflint.com .  At the moment I can't upload images because I just joined this site, but please know that the sprite menu is in the upper header area on the beta site.  The fourth image to the right is being forced down to the next line in Chrome.  For me, it displays fine in Firefox 28.0.

I thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: you should put all your code into code blocks with either ctrl+k or four indent spaces :) it is very hard to read as it is presented at the moment.

Comment: Thank you sabithpocker.  I will make this a habit from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may be the possible solution

remove float property of .horizontal-menu and update below properties in respective CSS

```
.horizontal-menu {
    text-align:center
}

.micrositestopnav ul{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Right now I can see 4 Li's with above method even if you increase or decrease number of Li it will still align center

Please check in other browsers as well Hope this helps.

Comment: I did the suggested changes but the sprite images are still floating to the left and they are not being centered.  This is occurring in both Firefox and Chrome now.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here is the replaced css code:  .micrositestopnav ul {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.micrositestopnav .horizontal-menu ul li {
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
    text-align:center;
}

Comment: check your code as I said text-align:center should be applied to div.horizontal-menu i.e. parent of #menu-microsites-topnav I guess by mistake you have applied to .horizontal-menu ul li

Comment: I'm still unable to center the sprite images. I appreciate your time and patience. I believe that the only way I could assign to the parent of .horizontal-menu ul li was by applying the text-align:center; to .micrositetopnav .horizontal-menu {....}.  Again I apologize and appreciate your help and ideas. I am using Ultimatum Framework within WordPress just to let you know.

.micrositestopnav .horizontal-menu {text-align:center;border:none;}
.micrositestopnav .horizontal-menu ul li {border:none;padding: 0px;}
.micrositestopnav ul {display: block;font-size: 13px;list-style: none;margin:0 auto;}

Comment: No probs. is it possible for you to update http://betabooks.matthewflint.com/ this site with updated code so I can inspect that and help you / create js fiddle /  screenshot link will be helpful to debug further

Comment: I just uploaded a video for you Pravin.  Thank you so much.  [lnk]http://youtu.be/nDLUNPIHEGk

Comment: Hi I checked your video. Its clear that li's are still floated and I can understand your trouble. unfortunately video is bit blurry so I can't figure out exact code. please find screenshot link http://postimg.org/image/vicswdfit/ something this can be helpful to you helpful link are 

1) you may be getting trouble due to float property li elements 
if you want to go with float: left property on li then
http://pmob.co.uk/pob/centred-float.htm


2) if you want to go with li as display: inline or display: inline-block

http://csswizardry.com/2011/01/create-a-centred-horizontal-navigation/

Comment: Thanks  lot Pravin. I'm not sure if you saw the link in the video description [link]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3736635/drbooks.css I am quite confused and hope to tackle this problem.  I will study the links above.  Again I appreciate all your input.

Comment: oops I took look now! You are closer and its always fun to play with CSS I guess if you check <div class="horizontal-menu" style="float:left"> inline css (float:left) is applied which taking precedence over style written in CSS file please remove that also .micrositestopnav .horizontal-menu ul li here you may need to add more propertys display:inline-block and float:none. Is it possible for you to share staging server link after making suggested changes

Comment: I guess it can be fun for pros but for the rest of us it can be an eye burning experience :).  Please know that I have contacted the support department at Ultimatum and I will be letting you know when this centering issue is achieved.  Thanks a lot Pravin and you have a great day or evening!

Comment: Pravin I could kiss you.  You were the solution.  I finally gave up on waiting for support and tried [link]http://pmob.co.uk/pob/centred-float.htm and it works like a charm.  Here goes:  .micrositestopnav .ultimatum-nav {
 float:right;
    position:relative;
    left:-50%;
    text-align:left;
 }

.micrositestopnav .horizontal-menu ul li {
 border:none;
 padding:0px;
 list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
} I'm new here on stackoverflow.com but if I could I would give you a five star rating.  Professional, patient and polite - what more could I ask for! Thanks a bunch seriously

Comment: Hahah It was pleasure to help you out! well I feel the same when someone else helps me out. if you think answer suits you then you can just click on up arrow below answer to mark it as correct answer! Good luck and welcome to stackoverflow :)